# TypeText doesn't work

Tags: android, android-espresso

Trying to test my sign in with espresso. If i click just on my field, then all work is well.

```
 ViewInteraction linearLayout = onView(
            allOf(childAtPosition(
                    allOf(withId(R.id.nameEditText),
                            childAtPosition(
                                    withId(R.id.inputLayout),
                                    0)),
                    0),
                    isDisplayed()));
    linearLayout.check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            .perform(click());
```

But if I need to put some text in this field, i have some problems:

```
ViewInteraction linearLayout = onView(
            allOf(childAtPosition(
                    allOf(withId(R.id.nameEditText),
                            childAtPosition(
                                    withId(R.id.inputLayout),
                                    0)),
                    0),
                    isDisplayed()));
    linearLayout.check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            .perform(typeText("SomeName"));
```

And get next error:

> android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'type text(SomeName)' on view '(Child at position 0 in parent (with id: com.fentury.android:id/nameEditText and Child at position 0 in parent with id: com.fentury.android:id/inputLayout)

**OR**

If i try do this way:

```
 ViewInteraction appCompatEditText = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.nameEditText),
                    withParent(withId(R.id.inputLayout)), isDisplayed()));
    appCompatEditText.check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            .perform(click()).perform(typeText("Dog"));
```

I have agait the same mistake:

> android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'type text(Dog)' on view '(with id: com.fentury.android:id/nameEditText and has parent matching: with id: com.fentury.android:id/inputLayout and is displayed on the screen to the user)'

How I can resolve this mistake?

Comment: Could you provide your layout? if you named it right, linearLayout can't type text.

Answer (score 6):

Are you using TextInputLayout?

Below worked for me with TextInputLayout.

```
    onView(
            allOf(
                    isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.nameEditText)),
                    isAssignableFrom(EditText.class)))
            .perform(typeText("some text"));
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer!